# Binding WPF control to OData

Tags: binding, odata

Is it possible to bind a WPF combobox control to an OData source and if so how does one do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Binding Data to Controls (WCF Data Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee373844.aspx) Microsoft has documented how to do this.